# Inconsistent String generation from unicode constructor and too long runtime problems

Tags: java, arrays, string, unicode

These are two questions in one:

I have this code here:

```
public String truncate(String input) {
        int[] arr = new int[5];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            arr[i] = input.codePointAt(i);
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
        return new String(arr, 0, arr.length);
        
    }
```

Which seems to work fine in most cases, however, regarding some emojis and other quite special characters (poker cards for example) it gets inconsistent. I printed out the Unicode points and they all seem to be in the Unicode size range.

To give an example:

Input:  -> Output: []

Unicode codepoints:
127182
56526
127160
56504
127173

So my first question would be: What is the problem here? Does the String constructor String(int[] codepoint, int offset, int length) only work in UTF-8 and ASCII or is this some kind of issue with UTF-16 encoding?

My second question is:

The task of the exercise is to truncate the input String to the first 5 letters.
For whatever reason I don't understand, fixing the code the following way, so it does not give an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, resulted in extremely slow runtime. The following changes were made:

From

```
int[] arr = new int[5];
```

To

```
int[] arr;
if (input.length() >= 5) {
   arr = new int[5];
} else {
   arr = new int[input.length()]
}
```

What cases could be possible that this would cause a problem with runtime? I don't have very much experience in Java and computer science in general (hence why I am practicing wiht exercises like these) but with my knowledge I currently don't see any errors here.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: A glyph (figure) may be created by more codepoints. If you print single codepoint, the system/shaping/font may take it as single figure (possibly incomplete). So: print a sequence of codepoints (or as in editor: you replace text/entire string). standard output is not so advanced (it show its age). For the second part: the problem is "character". You should check "figure/glyph" or length, but so complex. Try ICU library (from Unicode)

Comment: If your task is “to truncate the input String to the first 5 letters”, why do you have to deal with Emojis? Emojis are not letters. But as Giacomo Catenazzi correctly said, a character may consist of multiple codepoints. You don’t need fancy Emojis to encounter the problem, take `"o̹"`, for example. When you are using Java 9 or newer, you can use `return input.replaceFirst("(\\X{5}).*", "$1");` to get the first five logical characters (or, technically, first five graphemes).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the index in `input.codePointAt(i)` is not a codepoint index but a `char` index and emojis are encoded as to `char`s (high and low surrogate). For these codepoints you need to increase the index by two.

You could rewrite your code as:

```
public String truncate(String input) {
    int[] arr = new int[5];
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < arr.length && j < input.len; i++){
        arr[i] = input.codePointAt(j);
        j += Character.charCount(arr[i]);
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
    return new String(arr, 0, arr.length);
}
```

This however has a problem if `input` has less than 5 codepoints. An improved version would be

```
public static String truncate(String input) {
    int[] arr = new int[5];
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0, j = 0; i < arr.length && j < input.length(); i++){
        arr[i] = input.codePointAt(j);
        j += Character.charCount(arr[i]);
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
    return new String(arr, 0, i);
}
```

Or you code use the `codePoints()` stream:

```
public String truncate(String input) {
    int[] arr = input.codePoints().limit(5).toArray();
    return new String(arr, 0, arr.length);
}
```

---

**Edit**: note that while this solves your problem with emojis it is still not a complete solution as this ignores [graphemes clusters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869673/what-is-a-graphemecluster-and-what-does-expressiblebyextendedgraphemeclusterlite) .

If you need to support grapheme clusters you have two possibilities.

When using Java 9 and later you can use the grapheme support added to regular expressions (as shown in a comment to your post).

```
public String truncate(String input) {
    return input.replaceFirst("(\\X{5}).*", "$1");
}
```

When using Java 20 and later you can take advantage of the added support for extended grapheme clusters in `BreakIterator` (adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/76109241).

```
public static String truncate(String input) {
    BreakIterator bi = BreakIterator.getCharacterInstance();
    bi.setText(input);
    return input.substring(0, bi.next(5));
}
```

I currently don't have any measurements to tell which of these two solutions is faster.